# Regex Get Numbers in Dash or Underscore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I need to get the numbers only in between either the dash or underscore or if the number is not between, get the last part after the underscore or dash.
Right now I only managed to get the numbers only.
Pls only adjust on the "Display Name" TextField. The given should be put on the "Name" TextField.

For example:

Example 1: **AB2C_192_A9**

```
Expected Output: 192
```

Example 2: AB2C-192_A9

```
Expected Output: 192
```

Example 3: AB2C-192-A9

```
Expected Output: 192
```

Example 4: AB2C-192

```
Expected Output: 192
```

Example 5: 192

```
Expected Output: 192
```

Example 6: ABC_192Z

```
  Expected Output: 192
```

Code

```
  <TextField
    disabled
    label="Display Name"
    variant="outlined"
    value={value && value?.match(/\d+/g)?.join("")}
  />
```

[[image: Edit BasicTextFields Material Demo (forked)]](https://codesandbox.io/s/basictextfields-material-demo-forked-v22563?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
<TextField
    disabled
    label="Display Name"
    variant="outlined"
    value={(value.match(/(?:^|[-_])(\d+)(?=[_-]|[^\d_-]*$)/) || ['',''])[1]}
/>
```

Here,

- `(?:^|[-_])` - matches either start of string, or `-`, or `_`
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits
- `(?=[_-]|[^\d_-]*$)` - either a `-` or `_` or any zero or more chars other than digits, `_` and `-` chars till the end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aOOJ4j/5).

Comment: @John See the update. Note the pattern with the negative lookahead needs a `\n` in the regex demo since the test is performed against a single multiline string, in the code, you do not need that `\n`.

Comment: @John Same, use reverse lookbehind with negated character class, or an alternation with `^`.

Comment: Thank you. How do we prevent the 'Display Name' to be broken. When I type something wrong the label overlaps the text input https://imgur.com/jAnIE1h

Comment: @John See the update.

Comment: Hi Wiktor. I've added another example. Example 6.

Comment: @John It goes against your question: "*Get Numbers Between Either dash or underscore*". Update the question to list *exact pattern requirements*.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew. I have updated my question. This will be the final list of examples

Comment: @John Check the current solution then.